# How do I customize the ember-bootstrap form.element so that the input uses a specific column size?

Tags: bootstrap-4, ember.js, ember-bootstrap

I'm using ember-bootstrap and the following element:

```
<form.element @controlType="text" @label="First Name:" @property="firstName" />
```

which produces the following HTML

```
<div class="form-group row">
  <label class="col-sm-4 col-form-label" for="ember198-field">First Name</label>

  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <input id="ember198-field" class="form-control" type="text">
  </div>
</div>
```

How do I go about customizing the `col-sm-10` in the enclosing `<div>` for the input element?

Answer (score 0):

1. Note that Ember Bootstrap forms have three layouts:

   - horizontal
   - vertical
   - inline

   You seem to be using the default horizontal layout. A different layout may be more suitable to you.

   See:

   - https://www.ember-bootstrap.com/api/classes/Components.Form.html#property_formLayout
   - https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/forms/#horizontal-form
   - https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/forms/#inline-forms
2. If you are cool with the horizontal layout and simply want to tweak column sizes, use the `@horizontalLabelGridClass` argument [on the form](https://www.ember-bootstrap.com/api/classes/Components.Form.html#property_horizontalLabelGridClass) or [on individual element](https://www.ember-bootstrap.com/api/classes/Components.FormElement.html#property_horizontalLabelGridClass). This will tweak the class on the `<label>` and the class on the sibling `<div>` will be adjusted accordingly.